# Wicket 8.x Migration Issues with AjaxFallBackLink

Tags: wicket

We are in process of migration our Web application from Wicket 6.30 to Wicket 8.11.0.
As a first step, placed below jars in the classpath.

wicket-auth-roles-8.11.0.jar
wicket-core-8.11.0.jar
wicket-datetime-8.0.0-M7.jar
wicket-extensions-8.11.0.jar
wicket-request-8.11.0.jar
wicket-util-8.11.0.jar
wicketstuff-inmethod-grid-8.11.0.jar

Addressed the compilation issues related to AjaxFallBackLink onClick() method .
Changed the method signature to public void onClick(Optional target).

We have a Html page

SettingsPanel.html

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/dtds.data/wicket-xhtml1.4-strict.dtd" lang="en">
    <wicket:panel>
    <a href="#" wicket:id="saveSettingsLink"><img wicket:id="saveIcon" /></a>
    </wicket:panel>
    </html>
```

SettingsPanel.java

```
AjaxFallbackLink<Serializable> settingsLink = new AjaxFallbackLink<Serializable>("saveSettingsLink") {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                      @Override
    public void onClick(Optional<AjaxRequestTarget> target) {
                            //some logic
    target.get().add(feedback);
                            
    }
     };
      Image img = new Image("saveIcon", new Model<Serializable>() {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
      public Serializable getObject() {
                            return new PackageResourceReference(SettingsPanel.class,"save.png");
                      }
      });
     img.add(new AttributeModifier("title", new StringResourceModel("saveTitle", ColumnSettingsLinkPanel.this,new Model<String>())));
    settingsLink.add(img);
```

With the above code, in Wicket 6.30, save image (save.png) gets displayed on the page and when user clicks on the image link, onlick(AjaxRequestTarget target) gets triggered.
Post migrating to Wicket 8.11.0, image is not displaying on the page and when user clicks on the image link, onClick(Optional target) getting triggered, but the target value is always Empty.

Below is the stack trace
ERROR - DefaultExceptionMapper - Unexpected error occurred

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
at java.base/java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:148)
at com.csc.pts.web.ui.ColumnSettingsLinkPanel$3.onClick(SettingsPanel.java:98)
at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.AjaxFallbackLink.onClick(AjaxFallbackLink.java:122)
at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.Link.onRequest(Link.java:189)
at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerRequestHandler.internalInvoke(ListenerRequestHandler.java:306)
at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerRequestHandler.invoke(ListenerRequestHandler.java:255)
at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerRequestHandler.java:215)
at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerRequestHandler.respond(ListenerRequestHandler.java:208)
at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RequestSettingRequestHandler.respond(RequestSettingRequestHandler.java:78)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:912)
at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerExecutor.execute(RequestHandlerExecutor.java:65)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:283)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:253)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:221)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:262)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:204)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:286)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Can you please advise on the changes required to make this functionality work with Wicket 8.11.0 version.

Thanks,
Satya

Comment: Why are you using an AjaxFallbackLink in the first place? If you expect an AjaxRequestTarget to be always present, just use an AjaxLink.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use

```
target.ifPresent(t -> t.add(feedback));
```

instead of

```
target.get().add(feedback);
```

Comment: in my case, target is always empty, hence target.ifPresent() is always false

Comment: Do you have Javascript enabled?

Comment: Yes, javascript enabled.

Comment: Check the JS console in your browser. Seems that something is wrong with tha Ajax JS (resources?) and thus the fallback is kicking in.

Comment: Thanks for the input. on Checking JS console, i could see several js and css files were not loaded by server stating "Failed to load resource: the server". Server was unable to load below resources